# Struggling to understand how React determines address of API server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

I have a project with a `client` folder containing a React app bootstrapped with `create-react-app`. I also have a `server` folder with an express API server running on `localhost:80`.

Originally, I ran my frontend and backend as separate servers, making requests to the API server by making requests with `fetch("url")` and using `"proxy": "localhost:80"` in my `package.json`

I have recently altered the project so that my server serves the static frontend files like so: `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")))`

I then tested running the `server` on two different ports `80 and 3000`, and the frontend and backend both worked perfectly but I believed it would only work when the server was run on port 80

How does my frontend now know where to call the API server when it is running on different ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Proxy` is used in the development environment and after that when you make `build` then its convert into the static `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS` files and that can be run in any port using node if you try that in a different port than it will also work as same

Proxy is not made for the production environment

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1087

Comment: Reading the provided link shows that the static files default to the same domain if provided with a relative url, which allows the app to work.